# Error when installing R package using Rstudio

Tags: r, rstudio

I want to install http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/mecdf/ using RStudio but when I use

```
> install.packages('C:\\Users\\jandre\\Desktop\\mecdf_0.6.1.tar.gz', repos=NULL, type="source")
```

I get this error:

```
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/jandre/Documents/R/win-library/3.1’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"C:/Program Files/R/R-3.1.1/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\jandre\Documents\R\win-library\3.1" "C:/Users/jandre/Desktop/mecdf_0.6.1.tar.gz"' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘C:/Users/jandre/Desktop/mecdf_0.6.1.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

This occurs in every package I want to install using the tar.gz file. I'm on Win7 x64. RStudio Version 0.98.1028

Comment: Have you followed the instruction for setting up your system for package building (to the letter)?

Comment: looks like a problem with the space in your file path, but I don't know how to fix it

Comment: @BenBolker: Yes I think the same, and I also don't know how to fix it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can't think of a way to fix this at the moment -- sorry -- but the [R administration manual](http://cran.stat.sfu.ca/doc/manuals/R-admin.html) says explicitly:

> Note that installing R into a directory whose path contains spaces is not supported, and at least some aspects (such as installing source packages) will not work.

I don't know why this doesn't bite people much more often, given that `C:/Program Files/...` seems like a relatively normal place to install things on Windows.

I would also expect that the double quotation marks around your R executable name (`"C:/Program Files/R/R-3.1.1/bin/x64/R"`) in the system call *should* have protected you from this problem ... ?

Comment: Hum.... maybe R should show this warning during installation.... just a suggestion! But is this a R installation folder problem or a Rstudio? just to see what I have to reinstall. Thanks

Comment: @jpcgandre This is a problem with your R installation.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message with the installation of some packages(under Windows 10 OS with R and Rstudio).

It seems that the R software (not R Studio) is dealing with the library where package are installed.

I uninstalled R and Rstudio and installed it a path without space (ex: C:\Program\R).I tried to load the packages that previously failed and it seemed to fix the problem.